# Token error with groovy in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, groovy, titan

Initially, I was developing my groovy code in a simple text editor, but I set up version control via NetBeans and so moved my code over. However, I'm getting an "unexpected token" error on code that actually runs fine.

```
class PWLoad {

def conf = new BaseConfiguration() {{
        setProperty("storage.backend", "cassandra")
        setProperty("storage.directory", "/tmp/pw")
        setProperty("storage.batch-loading", true)
}}

def g = TitanFactory.open(conf)
def mgmt = g.getManagementSystem()

//This will be generated as "feature_type:geneId"
def objectId = mgmt.makePropertyKey('objectID').dataType(String.class).unique().make()
//Type of relationship between vertices -- all pairwise for this batch load script
def pairwise = mgmt.makeEdgeLabel('pairwise').dataType(String.class).multiplicity(Multiplicity.MULTI).make()
//Identifies these objects as bioentities, as opposed to drugs or other objects we may add later
def bioentity = mgmt.makeVertexLabel('bioentity').make();

//Vertex properties
def name = mgmt.makePropertyKey('name').dataType(String.class).make()
def chr = mgmt.makePropertyKey('chr').dataType(String.class).make()
def start = mgmt.makePropertyKey('start').dataType(Integer.class).make()
def end = mgmt.makePropertyKey('end').dataType(Integer.class).make()
def strand = mgmt.makePropertyKey('strand').dataType(Character.class).make()


/*
Edge properties -- inline comment corresponds to column #:
*/
def correlation = mgmt.makePropertyKey('correlation').dataType(Decimal.class).make() //3
def sample_size = mgmt.makePropertyKey('sample_size').dataType(Decimal.class).make() //4
def min_log_p_uncorrected = mgmt.makePropertyKey('min_log_p_uncorrected').dataType(Decimal.class).make() //5
def bonferroni = mgmt.makePropertyKey('bonferroni').dataType(Decimal.class).make() //6
def min_log_p_corrected = mgmt.makePropertyKey('min_log_p_corrected').dataType(Decimal.class).make() //7
def excluded_sample_count_a = mgmt.makePropertyKey('excluded_sample_count_a').dataType(Decimal.class).make() //8
def min_log_p_unused_a = mgmt.makePropertyKey('min_log_p_unused_a').dataType(Decimal.class).make() //9
def excluded_sample_count_b = mgmt.makePropertyKey('excluded_sample_count_b').dataType(Decimal.class).make() //10
def min_log_p_unused_b = mgmt.makePropertyKey('min_log_p_unused_b').dataType(Decimal.class).make() //11
def genomic_distance = mgmt.makePropertyKey('genomic_distance').dataType(Integer.class).make() //12


//Create index of ObjectId to speed map building

mgmt.buildIndex('byObjectId', Vertex.class).addKey(objectId).unique().buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.commit()

g.commit()
```

}

I'm getting the token error at the very bottom @ mgmt.buildIndex(). Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a number of things, but typically, an unexpected token error means you might have an extra comma, space, or character that doesn't belong there, like in the function call.

If you know what types of params `buildIndex` expects, it can be determined if it's an issue with the string being passed in i.e., `byObjectId`, or if any of the other chained functions are not properly called.

The fact that this was once working, and now it's not, might mean some library isn't being imported. I would turn on syntax highlighting for errors in NetBeans and it will usually tell you where something is getting passed in, or that's there that doesn't belong there.